# Invalid syntax error using Requests library with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm using the Requests library with Python 2.7 and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/workspaces/controller/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 14, in <module>
    import charset_normalizer as chardet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/charset_normalizer/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .api import from_bytes, from_fp, from_path, normalize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/charset_normalizer/api.py", line 38
    sequences: bytes,
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I installed Requests with the following command:

```
sudo pip install requests -t /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

The file I'm running is just main.py with the content:

```
import json
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print('hello world')
```

I have both Python 3.6 and 2.7 installed and selected Python 2.7 as the interpreter in VS Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this issue; the package is expecting to be executed with Python 3, not Python 2.